# Example of a plane embedding that contains a 3-cycle but every face has at least degree 4

Tags: graph-theory

Here is a plane embedding that contains a 3-cycle but every face has at least degree 4.
[image: an example of a plane embedding]

I wonder that if it is possible to construct such a graph but without introducing bridges?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

The trick is that you need some of your faces to have odd degrees (otherwise the graph is bipartite, and then cannot have a 3-cycle).

[image]